# How often does profile-sync-daemon sync?

Tags: io, browser, tmpfs

How often does `profile-sync-daemon` synchronize the browser profile to disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an hour. This is defined in [`psd-resync.timer`](https://github.com/graysky2/profile-sync-daemon/blob/master/init/psd-resync.timer)